# Making Array that named by a const

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to categorize my commands and make an array or object like:

```js
my commands = [Music[mymusiccommand1,mymusiccommand2], Fun[myfuncommand1,myfuncommand2]]
```

I've got all my commands into different files and I'm exporting their categories

```js
module.exports ={category:"Music",name:"Play",description: "Plays music"},
```

I can access their categories and make an array using them

```js
commands = commands.array();
categorydup =  commands.map(function (obj){return obj.category});
categories = [...new Set(categorydup)]

console.log(categories);
```

Console:

```js
[ 'Music', 'Fun', 'etc.', 'etc.' ]
```

But I can't go further and I can't push my commands into them because they are not arrays, but I couldn't figure out how to turn category names into arrays or objects.

Note: I want to get category names from `module.exports`; not write them by hand

Comment: Might you want an object instead of an array. The object would look like `mycommands ={Music: [mymusiccommand1,mymusiccommand2], Fun:[myfuncommand1,myfuncommand2]}`  Each array of commands would be associated with a different property of your `mycommands` object

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Most efficient method to groupby on an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: Build an object like `const objects = [{
    Music: {
        commands: ["command1", "command2"]
    },
    Fun: {
        commands: ["command1" , "command2"]
    }
}]

objects.forEach(val => console.log(val))`

Comment: found the answer on https://www.robinwieruch.de/javascript-groupby thanks for all your comments